# Unit test for throwing RejectedExecutionException by Java thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

I am new to using Java thread pool. Now i have a use case for unit test when a new task comes and current thread number is max number and queue is full. I know in this case `RejectedExecutionException` will be thrown. But how to best produce this scenario, what i can think of now is something like this:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1);
ExecutorService ex = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 60L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
int rejected = 0;
try{
    while (true){
        ex.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("Queue remaining size: " + queue.remainingCapacity());
            System.out.println("Thread amount in pool: " + ((ThreadPoolExecutor)ex).getPoolSize() + "\n");
        });
    }
}
catch (RejectedExecutionException e){
    System.out.println(++rejected);
}
```

This is basic idea and i need to convert this using EasyMock if it is right way. I wonder if there is better way if using EasyMock instead of keep submitting task until thread and queue is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is basic idea and i need to convert this using EasyMock if it is right way. I wonder if there is better way if using EasyMock instead of keep submitting task until thread and queue is full.

Anything that EasyMock would do would most likely take more code than your anonymous `Runnable`.  You could certainly do it but you would use an `IAnswer` object instead of the `Runnable` so I'm not sure it's much better.

The real question is what are you testing?  Are you really making sure that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is doing it's job or are you really trying to mock out an `ExecutorService` or as @Warren mentioned a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I'd do a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in your `Runnable` and submit 4 of them instead of the `while` loop.  You can also create one object at the start and submit it multiple times.  Please excuse the Java 7 code:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);
ExecutorService ex = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 60L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
};
try {
    ex.submit(runnable); // 1st thread
    ex.submit(runnable); // 2nd thread
    ex.submit(runnable); // 1st queued
    ex.submit(runnable); // rejected
} catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println("rejected");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with EasyMock in particular, but the general approach should be to mock out the ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: I support this and the way to do so is to remove the instantiation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and the `LinkedBlockingQueue` it depends on out of the class and inject it (preferably as constructor argument). Then it is easy to replace `ThreadPoolExecutor` by a mock. Since `ThreadPoolExecutor` is implementing the interface `Executor` the constructor parameter should be of that interface type.

Answer (score 0):

You might move the execution code to a new class where you can easily mock out the dependencies:

```
class MyExecuter extends Executer{
  private final ExecuterService executerService;
  private final PrintStream out;
  MyExecuter(ExecutorService executerService, PrintStream out){
    this.executerService  =  executerService;
    this.out  =  out;
  }
  @override 
   public void execute(Runnable r) {
     int rejected = 0;
     try{
        while (true)
        {
            executerService.submit(() -> {
               // do your business logic which usually does not care about the executor or the queue...
            });
        }
    }
    catch (RejectedExecutionException e)
    {
        out.println(++rejected);
    }

   }
}
```

Your code would change to this:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1);
ExecutorService ex = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 60L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
Executor mex = new MyExcecutor(ex, System.out);
mex.execute();
```

Now you can create a Test for `MyExcecutor` that gets mocks for `ExecutorService` and `PrintStream` so that you can verify interaction with them.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution:

Call [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) before submitting the task.

If you call `submit()` after `shutdown(`), you will get this type of execption:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task MyRunnable@3dcc0a0f
rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
```